# Union select using value returned from previous select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database set up like this with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     username varchar(20), 
     password varchar(30),
     auth_ip varchar(15),
     account_type varchar(10),
     server_name varchar(20)
    );

CREATE TABLE servers 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     name varchar(20), 
     address varchar(30),
     reserved boolean,
     user varchar(20)
    );
```

I am trying to write a query which allows me to search for users by username, and then include the information for from the servers table for the row where server_name is name. So for example, I might have 200 users, and 5 servers, so when I search for username `foo521` it returns the information from the user table, as well as from the server table for the server defined by server_name.

I'm new to SQL, so from basic googlefu I thought the best option would be to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = "foo"
UNION
SELECT address FROM servers WHERE name = something.server_name
```

The important thing is that this returns the results with one query, rather than multiples. Can anyone give some input? I'm using SQLite so AFAIK it must be a flat file database but I could be wrong about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do something of this nature:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM `users` AS u
INNER JOIN `servers` AS s
    ON u.server_name = s.name
WHERE u.username = 'foo'
```

I would look up how to join tables like [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins.php)  Things to point out that would see in both @Lamak's post and mine:

- Inner joins will only display data that has some tie in both tables; if it doesn't exist in one or the other, the record won't show up.
- Left/Right joins will give you null results if one of the referenced tables doesn't have correlating information.
- **Always use aliases, and specify them in your select statement.**  If you don't, it will return return records on all joined tables.  This is fine if you're expecting that to happen.
- As pointed out by @Winkbrace, make sure you set your primary / foreign keys appropriately.  One of your Primary id's should be a foreign key in the other table.  Once you do, you should have something like the following on the join:

  ```
    INNER JOIN `servers` AS s ON u.server_id = s.server_id
  ```

Comment: also you want to have the server id in your users table, not the server name, as the id has a primary key index and your query will be faster.

Comment: @winkbrace; This is true; thanks for the catch, as just modified Lamak's answer with a repost to show a bit of variety.   I'll modify the post to show otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM `users` AS u
LEFT JOIN `servers` AS s
    ON u.server_name = s.name
WHERE u.username = 'foo'
```

Comment: That returns every field in servers. How do I get it to return just address?

Comment: `SELECT <columns here>`, so you can do: `SELECT u.username, s.address`